# Text Engraving effect in UILabel

Tags: iphone, uilabel

How can we bring the Engraved effect of a UILabel's Text?

I wanted the effect as provided in the snapshot I have provided.

I could not add the image, so I have added the Link where I have hosted it.
[Image](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?3c017fb62e.png)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using a light text color, set the shadow to a color darker than your text and move the shadow up 1 pixel.

If you're using a dark text color, set the shadow to a color lighter than your text and move the shadow down 1 pixel.

Comment: Depends on the background color too.